# Change mouse cursor when dragging in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

When drag something, a mouse cursor looks like this.

[image]

Is it possible to change the shape of the mouse cursor?

```js
document.querySelector('.item').addEventListener('drag', function(event) {
  // I try to this in html or event.target but it didn't work.
  document.querySelector('html').style.cursor = url('something_I_want.jpg');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the mouse cursor when dragging elements in JavaScript, you can use the `dragstart`, `drag`, and `dragend` events along with the CSS `cursor` property. Here's a step-by-step guide on how to achieve this:

1. **HTML Structure**: Create an HTML structure with the element you want to make draggable.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="draggableElement" draggable="true">Drag me!</div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

2. **CSS**: Create a CSS file to define the cursor styles for different drag states.

```css
#draggableElement {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    cursor: pointer; /* Initial cursor style */
}

#draggableElement.dragging {
    cursor: move; /* Cursor style while dragging */
}
```

3. **JavaScript**: Create a JavaScript file to handle the drag events and change the cursor style accordingly.

```js
const draggableElement = document.getElementById("draggableElement");

draggableElement.addEventListener("dragstart", (event) => {
    // Add dragging class to change cursor style
    draggableElement.classList.add("dragging");

    // Set the data that will be transferred during the drag
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", "Dragging element");
});

draggableElement.addEventListener("dragend", () => {
    // Remove dragging class to revert cursor style
    draggableElement.classList.remove("dragging");
});
```

---

In this example, the `dragstart` event is used to add a class to the draggable element, changing the cursor style while dragging. The `dragend` event removes the class, reverting the cursor style back to the default.

Remember that the availability of drag-and-drop events and the ability to customize cursor styles during drag can vary across browsers and platforms. It's a good practice to test your implementation on different browsers to ensure consistent behavior.

```js
const draggableElement = document.getElementById("draggableElement");

draggableElement.addEventListener("dragstart", (event) => {
  // Add dragging class to change cursor style
  draggableElement.classList.add("dragging");

  // Set the data that will be transferred during the drag
  event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", "Dragging element");
});

draggableElement.addEventListener("dragend", () => {
  // Remove dragging class to revert cursor style
  draggableElement.classList.remove("dragging");
});
```

```css
#draggableElement {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Initial cursor style */
}

#draggableElement.dragging {
  cursor: move;
  /* Cursor style while dragging */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="draggableElement" draggable="true">Drag me!</div>
</body>

</html>
```